# Accessing an object created in another view controller at any time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a logic issue. I need to access an instance of an object from another class.

I have a class called `FacebookController`. It has several delegate methods in it, for example `fbDidLogin`. First the `facebookloginButtonClicked` method gets executed when the user clicks on a button, and after some internal processing, the `fbDidLogin` method will get called, and the user will log in to the application. (All of this works perfectly).

Now I need to log out from the application. There is a delegate method called `logout`, and I have to call it as `[facebook logout]`.

I have added a method called `-(void) logoutFacebook`. When the user clicks the logout button, the following method is called. The logout method is as follows;

```
-(void) logoutFacebook {
   [facebook logout];    
}
```

Logout works only if I log out (call `logoutFacebook` method) **from the same viewController**.

For instance if I am in a class called `Student`, I am trying to call the `logoutFacebook` method of `FacebookController`. My approach is as follows;

```
FacebookController *facebookController = [[FacebookController alloc]]init;

[facebookController logoutFacebook];
```

This doesn't work, because by doing this, it will create a new instance of `FacebookController` . So I need to somehow access the original `facebook` object which was in the `FacebookController` (which was created after login). How do I get access this object ?

The code:

```
-(void)facebookloginButtonClicked:(id)sender{
 facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"3232232" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {

        facebook.accessToken  = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {        
        [facebook authorize:nil];      

    }
}
- (void)fbDidLogin {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[ facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[ facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    }

-(void) logoutFacebook {
       [facebook logout];    
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `FacebookController.m` class add this code above the @implementation

```
static FacebookController* Object;
```

add the following function to the .h file

```
+ (FacebookController *) sharedInstance;
```

Implementation of the above function in the .m file

```
+ (FacebookController *) sharedInstance
{
if( Object == nil)
{
Object = [[FacebookController alloc]]init;
}

return Object;

}
```

Now wherever you want to use the Facebook object ..use it like this

```
[FacebookController sharedInstance];
```

Now you will only have one instance of `FacebookController` class in your app's whole lifetime..This is called **Singleton pattern**..You can find google it to get more detail on it.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
- https://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will google it. Is there any good tutorial you recommend ?